# sprintf multiple bytes using hex as parameters

Tags: c, string-formatting, uart

I know this is simple, but I'm missing it somehow.

```
szTemp[1024] = "";
sprintf((char*)szTemp, "%c%c", 0x7e, 0x00);
```

Only outputs `~` over UART.  Any more than 1 byte doesn't work.  This does work, however:

```
sprintf((char*)szTemp, "some test string");
```

Gives: `some test string`

**Update:** The XBEE module I'm communicating with takes API command frames.  One of which is a data transmission frame.  Without going into the structure of the frame, the bytes to be sent are:

`7E 00 17 10 01 00 13 A2 00 41 66 0F 42 FF FE 00 00 74 65 73 74 20 64 61 74 61 CA`

I can write to the uart by setting the value of the transmit register and waiting for it to finish:

`COMTX = 0X7E;
while ((COMSTA0 & 0x40) == 0x00){}`

Comment: The cast `(char)szTemp` is terrible, the compiler must complain about that. `sprintf(char *, const char *, ...)` is the signature. Also, the NULL ASCII character is non-printable, so you shouldn't be confused that only one character is printed. What did you expect would be printed? Furthermore, I checked the ASCII table and the tilde `~` is at 0x7e. Are you not using ASCII?

Comment: You're right, no it was 0x7e.  It seems the problem is that I'm trying to send bytes that are not ascii using sprintf to format them, and apparently it doesn't like that.  I'm going to try to write to the UART directly using the TX register in the uC.

Comment: For different character sets, you need to convert in between those. Then you can go ahead and use `sprintf` to have all the fun you want. To reiterate, NULL is non-printable in ASCII, it won't be printed by it's very definition. Similarly, the bell character `\a` or `\v`, a vertical tab. Or what do you mean "it doesn't like that"?

Comment: Thanks I was also trying (char*) not sure how the * went missing.  I am not using any character set, the device I'm communicating with (XBEE) uses a frame format that uses bytes not in a character set for commands.

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?  I understand you're trying to send bytes/characters to a UART.  That's straightforward.  It may be helpful to use `sprintf` to construct a string of characters to be sent to the UART.  That's also straightforward.  I doubt there are any exotic transformations you have to do before sending bytes to the UART, but if there are, `sprintf` is probably *not* the tool to perform them.  What does your UART-sending, TX-using code look like, anyway?

Comment: Based on the two examples you described, it sounds like you've got some code that transmits the contents of `szTemp` to the UART, and it sounds like that code's working fine.

Comment: @SteveSummit I just posted an update of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to construct a sequence of bytes in `szTemp`.
It sounds like those bytes might not all be printable characters.
It sounds like the code that transmits the contents of `szTemp` to your UART is working fine.

If you just want to construct a string of arbitrary bytes, you don't even need `sprintf`.  (It could probably be made to work using `sprintf`, but it'll be more cumbersome and won't buy you anything.)  Try this:

```
szTemp[0] = 0x7e;
szTemp[1] = 0x17;
szTemp[2] = 0x10;
szTemp[3] = 0x01;
szTemp[4] = 0x00;

/* now your existing code for transmitting szTemp` to UART */
```

Based on the examples you posted, it sounds like your existing transmit-the-string-to-the-UART code is stopping when it reaches a 0 byte, which makes sense if the string is a null-terminated C string.  But obviously, if the bytes to be sent are arbitrary binary bytes which might include `0x00`, you don't want to stop at the first 0.  So that code may need reworking.

---

I'm speculating now, but you *might* want something like this:

```
char szTemp[] = { 0x7E, 0x00, 0x17, 0x10, 0x01, 0x00, 0x13, 0xA2, 0x00,
                  0x41, 0x66, 0x0F, 0x42, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x74,
                  0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61, 0xCA };
int nch = 27;

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < nch; i++) put_one_character(szTemp[i]);
}

void put_one_character(char c)
{
    COMTX = c;
    while((COMSTA0 & 0x40) == 0x00) {}
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like it should work, but for some reason, the output is not right.  I'm getting: `0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x62, 0x7d, 0x7f...`

Comment: my problem was the scope of the szTemp array.  I had it outside the main function, and the for loop was inside an interrupt routine.  Once I moved the szTemp initializer inside the interrupt routine, it started working.  Thanks.